# Irreducible Markov chains as ergodic dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

Let $(X_i)$ be an irreducible Markov chain on a finite set $E$ with transition matrix $P$ and invariant distribution $\pi$.
Let $T$ be the shift on $E^{\mathbb{N}}$,
$$ T: E^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow E^{\mathbb{N}} $$
$$ (x_0,x_1,x_2,...)\mapsto (x_1,x_2,x_3,...) $$

The french wiki on Markov chains says [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha%C3%AEne_de_Markov#Loi_forte_des_grands_nombres_et_ergodicit%C3%A9) that the following dynamical system $(E,\Pi,T)$ is ergodic ($E$ is endowed with the product topology and $\Pi$ is the "product" measure). I see why it is measure preserving, can anyone help me to show that for a measurable set $A$, $T^{-1}(A)\subset A$ implies $\Pi(A)=1$ or $0$?

Thank you

Comment: $\Pi$ isn't a product measure, it's the Markov measure on the space of sample paths defined by the given initial distribution and transition probabilities

Comment: There is a nice proof in Peter Walters's book _Introduction to Ergodic Theory_, Theorem 1.19

Comment: Thank you Adam!

Comment: For a sufficient condition for ergodicity for Markov chains defined on any state spaces see Proposition 8.8 and Corollary 8.9 here https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf3953/Material/L8.pdf. Note that the proof is written in case of a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_\pi$ but actually everything can be done in case of a general possibly non-finite measure $\mu$ provided it can be disintegrated as $\mu(dx_0,dx_1,dx_2,...)=\mu_0(dx_0)k(x_0,dx_1)k(x_1,dx_2)...$ for a probability transition kernels $k$. This is always the case for Markov chains $(\mu_0,P)$ (since $k=P$).

Comment: (continued) When the state space is a countable set, we can therefore conclude that a Markov chain $(\mu_0,P)$ with $P$ irreducible and recurrent and $\mu_0$ is the unique stationary measure for $P$ induces a measure preserving ergodic dynamical system (since we irreducibility and recurrence guarantee uniqueness of the stationary measure $\mu_0$). The vice versa is also true.